# Created Core Data Entity on child context faulted in SwiftUI body

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Why wouldn't I be able to use this `draft` object within the view's body?

I've also tried:

- Setting draft to a State object passing in the entity as a wrappedValue.
- Using the `mainQueueConcurrencyType` for the child context

```swift
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    public func newChildContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        moc.parent = self
        return moc
    }
}

struct InternalContentView: View {
    private var context: NSManagedObjectContext

    @State private var draft: PlayerEntity

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.context = context

        let childContext = context.newChildContext()
        draft = PlayerEntity.create(context: childContext)

        print("draft: \(draft)")
        print("draft id: \(draft.id?.uuidString ?? "unknown id")")
        print("draft is faulted: \(draft.isFault)")
    }

    var body: some View {
        printv("draft: \(draft)")
        printv("draft id: \(draft.id?.uuidString ?? "unknown id")")
        printv("draft is faulted: \(draft.isFault)")
        Text("")
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
draft: <PlayerEntity: 0x600001de6170> (entity: PlayerEntity; id: 0x600003e4fc60 <x-coredata:///PlayerEntity/t54BF6346-6299-479F-AD02-AC61AC056CCF2>; data: {
    email = nil;
    games =     (
    );
    id = "51BDEE17-DCA4-4EB9-8A56-0780ACFF55B3";
    "name_" = nil;
    teams =     (
    );
})
draft id: 51BDEE17-DCA4-4EB9-8A56-0780ACFF55B3
draft is faulted: false

draft: <PlayerEntity: 0x600001de6170> (entity: PlayerEntity; id: 0x600003e4fc60 <x-coredata:///PlayerEntity/t54BF6346-6299-479F-AD02-AC61AC056CCF2>; data: <fault>)
draft id: unknown id
draft is faulted: true
```

Comment: Probably because the child context only exists within the `init`, make it a property instead.

Comment: Thank you! Please answer it below and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your child context only lives within the `init` but you will need to have access to it outside as well (or rather at least until you call `save()` on it)

So make it a property instead

```
struct InternalContentView: View {
    private var context: NSManagedObjectContext
    private var childContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    ...
  
    init() {
        self.context = context
        childContext = context.newChildContext()
```